# DataTables warning Requested unknown parameter

Tags: jquery, jsf, warnings, datatables

First of all I would like to say I search and explored for our the other threads regarding this issue but could not find an answer to my problem.
I use a h:datatable which i extended via jquery datatables. 
Data is displayed correctly as long as there is data in the table.
As soon as the ArrayList, which gets the data from a datatabase via backing bean, is empty I get this notification. Along with that, all my JavaScript functionaly gets broken after the notification, so no other JAvaScirpt works ion the page until there is another succesfull call with some data in the ArrayList as a response.

```
$('#rating-table').dataTable({
"sDom" : 'T<"clear">lfrtip',    
"sDefaultContent" : "",
"bFilter": false,
"bSort" : false});
```

...

```
<h:dataTable id="rating-table" width="800px"
value="#{rating.boniHistorieList}" var="r">
```

...

```
private List<BoniHistorie> boniHistorieList;
public List<BoniHistorie> getBoniHistorieList() { ...
}
```